# Converting a BST to an array

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, binary-search-tree

I have a binary tree where I need to have it sorted inside an array and then return it. This is the function and where I am currently

```
struct treeNode
{
    int data;
    struct treeNode* left;
    struct treeNode* right;
};

typedef struct treeNode* BSTree;

static int* writeSortedToArray(const BSTree tree)
{
    int i=0;
    int leng = numberOfNodes(tree);
    int *arrayBST = malloc(leng*sizeof(int));

}
```

I dont know how to continue or if even the allocation part is correct any advice on how to make this work would be appreciated and if similar question has been asked before I would love it if anyone would guide me to it.

Comment: It's not a linked list, it's a tree. Traverse it from the root, writing out the root value, then traverse the left subtree, then the right subtree, recursively.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your problem has two parts: allocating an array of the correct size and type, and iterating over the tree. I strongly advise you to get these pieces working separately, before you try to integrate them. Look up "inorder traversal" to see how to traverse the tree and get the elements in sorted order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to allocate your array properly.

This is how you can do it:

```
int* arrayBST = (int*)malloc(leng*sizeof(int));
```

Read more about it here: [Dynamic Memory Allocation in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c-using-malloc-calloc-free-and-realloc/)

Now, to store the tree in sorted order in the array, you need to traverse the left section of the tree, then root, and then the right section (you can do it recursively). This is called Inorder traversal ([Tree Traversals](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/)). Just pass the above array in the inorder traversal function and store the root values while traversing.

The inorder traversal function can be like this:

```
typedef struct treeNode* BSTree; 

// you can pass the index in the array as reference
void inorderTraversal(const BSTree tree, int* arrayBST, int* ind) {
    if(tree) {
        //store the left subtree
        inorderTraversal(tree->left, arrayBST, ind);

        //store current root value
        arrayBST[*ind] = tree->data;
        (*ind)++;

        //store the right subtree
        inorderTraversal(tree->right, arrayBST, ind);
    }
}

static int* writeSortedToArray(const BSTree tree)
{
    int ind = 0;
    int leng = numberOfNodes(tree); 
    int* arrayBST = (int*)malloc(leng*sizeof(int));
    inorderTraversal(tree, arrayBST, &ind);
    return arrayBST;
}
```

I hope this helps. If you have any doubts, feel free to ask.

Comment: `int* arrayBST = (int*)malloc(leng*sizeof(int));` --> `int* arrayBST = malloc(leng*sizeof(int));` or better `int* arrayBST = malloc(leng*sizeof *arrayBST);`

Comment: Hi, I get an error at `inorderTraversal(const BSTree tree, int* arrayBST, int& ind) ` error of token &

Comment: @Divyalok Jaiswal  if I remove the `&` the array doesnt get fild with the right numbers have tried debugging.

Comment: @Drakechmon Sorry for the mistake. I code in C++. So, by mistake used the reference operator (&) used in C++. I've updated the code for C (using pointers).